# question about equivalence relation ,when there exist a limitation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $R$ is a relation form $A$ to $B$,where $A ,B$ are two arbitrary sets,let $D⊆A$, then define :
$$R∣D:{(x,y):x∈D}$$
hence $R∣D$ is a relation from $D$ to $B$.

> prove:
>   $$R∣D=R∩(D×Im(R))$$

my try:
\begin{align}
&(x,y)∈R∩(D×Im(R))≡\\
&(x,y)∈R ∧ (x,y)∈(D×Im(R))≡ \tag*{Definition of ∩ }\\
&(x,y)∈R ∧ (x∈D ∧ y∈Im(R) ≡ \tag*{Definition of Cartesian product}\\
&((x,y)∈R ∧ x∈D)∧ ((x,y)∈R ∧ y∈Im(R))≡ \tag*{distributive law}\\
&((x,y)∈R ∧ x∈D)∧ ((x,y)∈R ∧ T)≡ \tag*{}\\
&((x,y)∈R∣D)∧ ((x,y)∈R)≡ \tag*{by definition}\\
&((x,y)∈R∣D ∩ R )≡ \tag*{Definition of ∧}\\
&( (x,y)∈R∣D) \tag*{D⊆A}\\
&{}\\
\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The correct defining of $R|D$ is 
$R|D = { (x,y) : x∈D, xRy }$.

Your proof is complicated and not clear.

If $x(R|D)y$, then $x$ in $D$, $xRy$.
Thus $y$ in $Im R$, so xRy and x(D×Im R)y.

If $xRy$ and $x(D×Im R)y$, then $x$ in $D$.
Whence $xRy$ and $x$ in $D$ so $x(R|D)y$.

Using that & thing in a question makes it difficult to work with.  Do not use it.